# Split a record into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server, Portfolio and Master. The portfolio holds inventory, while the master table defines the room types and number of bedrooms.

```
select
    PropertyNumber,
    Unit,
    Rent,
    Code
from Portfolio
```

The above query returns the following records:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 111 | **500** | **2BD** |
| 01 | 112 | 200 | 1BD |

While the below query returns the following:

```
select
    Property,
    Unit,
    Duplex
from [Master]
```

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1BD | 1 |
| 01 | **2BD** | **2** |
| 01 | 3BD | 3 |

I'm trying to split rows based on the Duplex column in my Master table. For example, in the initial output, I'd like to split that first record into two rows based on the 2BD data (and also divide the Rent column by that number). In other words, the final result would look like this:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 111 | 250 | 2BD |
| 01 | 111 | 250 | 2BD |
| 01 | 112 | 200 | 1BD |

Comment: `JOIN` the tables and divide by the row `COUNT` for the `Unit`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't write your query for you, but I'll tell you how to do it, if I understand the question.

IIUC you want to produce N rows for `master` based on `duplex`.

To produce N rows, create a little table, perhaps like this:

```
select distinct duplex as n into #N
```

then

```
select m.* from master as m join #N
on duplex <= n
```

The rest is easy: extend the join to `portfolio`, and divide `rent` by `duplex`.

Comment: Thank you James! That was perfect. The temp table is exactly what I needed to do. Much appreciated.